# connected neighbours in a java 2d array

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm designing an engine for a game which has a 2D array like this:

```
0,1,1,2,0
0,1,2,1,1
1,0,1,0,2
2,1,2,0,0
2,0,1,0,0
```

I'm stuck at the "game over" condition as it has to check if the 1's or 2's are connected.
It should declare the player with 1's as winner and return this:

```
 1 1
 1   1 1
1  1
1
  1
    1
```

I've tried using recursion by checking every position in the array and checking its neighbors in all 8 directions but the method took 45 seconds to run which is inefficient.

Does anyone have any ideas?  A pseudo-code example would be appreciated (I'm a slow learner).

Comment: can you elaborate on the condition? why is p1 the winner?

Comment: You want to check if all 1s are 8-connected? (Or all 2s, in case of player 2?)

Comment: can u post what you tried?

Comment: Try [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), should take linear time

Comment: is it intentional or a typo that the `2` at `(0, 3)` changed to a `1` in the return state?

Comment: it is a typo and p1 is the winner as all of it's elements are connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and make a duplicate graph `a[n][n]` with `a[i][j] = 1` if `i` and `j` are connected.

Then you can do the following:

```
int count = 0;

void dfs(int i)
{
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        if(A[i][k] == 1 && !visited[k])
        {
            count++;
            visited[k] = 1;
            dfs(k);
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; i < n;i++)
{
    if(!visited[i])
    {
        count=1;
        visited[i]=1;
        dfs(i);
        // map i with count .. here
    }
}
```

So once you have done mapping count of nodes in a network with one of its node .

You'll find value count and if count == total_no_of_1's

If so then network 1 is connected .if not then same with 2's and and declare result .

Comment: thank you for this you really saved me alot of hours my code was something like this in recursion but it turned out that i counted the same nodes over and over so thank's again

Answer (score 2):

What you need is that:

[Connected_component_labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

This gives a pseudo code,

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips:

- If possible, keep track of how many 1's and 2's there are from the beginning.
- When checking if they're connected, you could use a `boolean` matrix and a counter, to keep track of which ones you've already checked and how many of them.
- Use recursion on the necessary neighbors instead of checking every position in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not so easy. It looks to me you can look at your matrix as a graph and you try to find out if your graph is connected. i.e. is the graph of 1s connected and is the graph of 2s connected. Here you see a [few algorithms](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_Connectivity). Since you are creating the graph you can also keep track of the groups of nodes a player is creating and upon creating a new node, you can check to how many groups is the new node connected and union whatever get connected by the new node (or create a new group containing your new node if it does not connect anything).

btw you can convert any recursion to a loop but this should be necessary only if your stack gets exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a [UnionFind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure from the beginning, each entry representing each cell. Initially, perform a Union on adjacent cells with the same values. When a player marks a cell, perform a union() with the adjacent cells if the value is the same as the player's value. In the Union find, you can keep track of the number of cells that have a value, when that number is equal to the number of times that value was inserted, you have a winner.

You also do it Linearly using the algorithm described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)